# Automatically export graphs for all the time series in a given data.frame, column by column, every X data points

Tags: r, graph, time-series, timeserieschart

I would very much appreciate your help.

Thank you very much and I hope you can help me as I am not really able to do anything like that by myself. If I am asking something that is not appropriate, I am really sorry and I do apologise in advance.

I need to visually inspect a lot of graphs (thousands) for two time series. One of the two is fixed (let's name it GW) and will not change, whilst the others (let's name them Pz1, Pz2, Pz3,...Pz n) will be different for each graph: basically, I need to visually compare GW with all the possible Pz, given a fixed-length (i.e., 10 data points).

The data are in a frame format, i.e.,:

```
structure(list(GW = c(0.08, 0.04, 0.35, 0.54, 0.39, 0.94, 0.51, 
0.01, 0.44, 0.63, 0.14, 0.79, 0.43, 0.73, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), Pz1 = c(-2.459826614, -2.905007821, -2.241113224, 
-1.549264338, -1.761962438, -1.282612221, -0.428828702, 1.659042479, 
2.63518648, 3.076022461, 1.886216859, 0.124473561, -1.025720789, 
-1.969461882, -2.216075605, -2.508858567, -2.495831241, -2.36513321, 
-2.295002655, -2.103511241, -1.009051105, -0.619616011, -0.941517493
), Pz2 = c(-2.916090168, -3.262459435, -2.455396094, -1.488106654, 
-0.417171756, -1.781014095, -0.605012986, 1.037062685, 1.977265974, 
2.587846362, 2.499228916, 1.0852274, -0.503736287, -1.829562138, 
-2.410220303, -2.135932209, -2.105646454, -2.79131286, -2.446274505, 
-2.412041743, -1.467408853, -1.207262381, -1.286558601), Pz3 = c(-2.507944967, 
-3.718722989, -2.812847708, -1.702389524, -0.356014073, -0.436223413, 
-1.10341486, 0.860878402, 1.355286181, 1.929925855, 2.011052817, 
1.698239458, 0.457017552, -1.307577636, -2.270320559, -2.330076907, 
-1.732720095, -2.401128073, -2.872454155, -2.563313593, -1.775939355, 
-1.665620129, -1.874204971), Pz4 = c(-2.526729696, -3.310577787, 
-3.269111262, -2.059841138, -0.570296943, -0.375065729, 0.241375822, 
0.362476528, 1.179101897, 1.307946062, 1.35313231, 1.210063358, 
1.07002961, -0.346823797, -1.748336058, -2.190177163, -1.926864794, 
-2.028201714, -2.482269368, -2.989493243, -1.927211205, -1.974150631, 
-2.332562719), Pz5 = c(-3.284551238, -3.329362517, -2.86096606, 
-2.516104692, -0.927748557, -0.5893486, 0.302533506, 1.70726721, 
0.680700023, 1.131761778, 0.731152517, 0.552142851, 0.58185351, 
0.266188261, -0.787582218, -1.668192661, -1.78696505, -2.222346412, 
-2.109343009, -2.599308456, -2.353390855, -2.125422481, -2.641093221
), Pz6 = c(-4.011896321, -4.087184059, -2.87975079, -2.107959491, 
-1.38401211, -0.946800213, 0.088250636, 1.768424893, 2.025490705, 
0.633359905, 0.554968233, -0.069836942, -0.076066996, -0.221987839, 
-0.174570161, -0.707438822, -1.264980548, -2.082446669, -2.303487708, 
-2.226382097, -1.963206068, -2.551602131, -2.792365071), Pz7 = c(-4.769878994, 
-4.814529142, -3.637572331, -2.12674422, -0.975866909, -1.403063767, 
-0.269200978, 1.554142023, 2.086648388, 1.978150587, 0.05656636, 
-0.246021225, -0.698046789, -0.879908346, -0.66274626, -0.094426764, 
-0.304226709, -1.560462167, -2.163587964, -2.420526796, -1.59027971, 
-2.161417344, -3.218544722)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-23L))
```

Basically, I am looking for something that can automatise the entire process and save all the graphs, individually, in a folder so I can patiently check them graphically.

On top of that, both A and B..., should be normalised (Z-Score) before being plotted (i.e., Z=x-mean/Standard deviation), should include some kind of coordinates so I can find them in the matrix (i.e., Graph #4=B5-B8, and ideally (it would be a dream) have also spearman correlation coefficient and RMSE values (please check link with the image at the bottom).

[Schematic summary of what I am trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nj5KO.png)

Unfortunately, I have no idea where to start from and your help would be immensely appreciated.

I am sorry if it is confusing and if you need further clarification please, do not hesitate to let me know and I will try to explain it better.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I can help with the first part of your question - automated saving of the plots.

```
library(tidyverse)

# this is your data, I have called it 'my_data'
my_data <- structure(list(GW = c(0.08, 0.04, 0.35, 0.54, 0.39, 0.94, 0.51, 0.01, 0.44, 0.63, 0.14, 0.79, 0.43, 0.73, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,NA, NA, NA, NA), 
                          Pz1 = c(-2.459826614, -2.905007821, -2.241113224, -1.549264338, -1.761962438, -1.282612221, -0.428828702, 1.659042479,2.63518648, 3.076022461, 1.886216859, 0.124473561, -1.025720789,-1.969461882, -2.216075605, -2.508858567, -2.495831241, -2.36513321, -2.295002655, -2.103511241, -1.009051105, -0.619616011, -0.941517493), 
                          Pz2 = c(-2.916090168, -3.262459435, -2.455396094, -1.488106654,-0.417171756, -1.781014095, -0.605012986, 1.037062685, 1.977265974,2.587846362, 2.499228916, 1.0852274, -0.503736287, -1.829562138,-2.410220303, -2.135932209, -2.105646454, -2.79131286, -2.446274505,-2.412041743, -1.467408853, -1.207262381, -1.286558601), 
                          Pz3 = c(-2.507944967,-3.718722989, -2.812847708, -1.702389524, -0.356014073, -0.436223413,-1.10341486, 0.860878402, 1.355286181, 1.929925855, 2.011052817,1.698239458, 0.457017552, -1.307577636, -2.270320559, -2.330076907,-1.732720095, -2.401128073, -2.872454155, -2.563313593, -1.775939355,-1.665620129, -1.874204971), 
                          Pz4 = c(-2.526729696, -3.310577787,-3.269111262, -2.059841138, -0.570296943, -0.375065729, 0.241375822,0.362476528, 1.179101897, 1.307946062, 1.35313231, 1.210063358,1.07002961, -0.346823797, -1.748336058, -2.190177163, -1.926864794,-2.028201714, -2.482269368, -2.989493243, -1.927211205, -1.974150631,-2.332562719), 
                          Pz5 = c(-3.284551238, -3.329362517, -2.86096606,-2.516104692, -0.927748557, -0.5893486, 0.302533506, 1.70726721,0.680700023, 1.131761778, 0.731152517, 0.552142851, 0.58185351,0.266188261, -0.787582218, -1.668192661, -1.78696505, -2.222346412,-2.109343009, -2.599308456, -2.353390855, -2.125422481, -2.641093221),
                          Pz6 = c(-4.011896321, -4.087184059, -2.87975079, -2.107959491,-1.38401211, -0.946800213, 0.088250636, 1.768424893, 2.025490705,0.633359905, 0.554968233, -0.069836942, -0.076066996, -0.221987839,-0.174570161, -0.707438822, -1.264980548, -2.082446669, -2.303487708,-2.226382097, -1.963206068, -2.551602131, -2.792365071),
                          Pz7 = c(-4.769878994,-4.814529142, -3.637572331, -2.12674422, -0.975866909, -1.403063767,-0.269200978, 1.554142023, 2.086648388, 1.978150587, 0.05656636,-0.246021225, -0.698046789, -0.879908346, -0.66274626, -0.094426764,-0.304226709, -1.560462167, -2.163587964, -2.420526796, -1.59027971,-2.161417344, -3.218544722)), 
                     class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-23L))


#~~~ step 1: transform the data from 'wide' format to 'long' format ~~~

my_data %>%
    pivot_longer(names_to = 'key', values_to = 'value', -GW) %>%
    {. ->> my_data_long}

# the data now looks like this:
# this 'long' format reduces the number of columns, and increases the number of rows. 
# Each row now refers to which column the data came from, and the value from the column, for each value of GW
  # GW    key   value
  # <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
  # 0.08  Pz1   -2.46
  # 0.08  Pz2   -2.92
  # 0.08  Pz3   -2.51
  # with many more rows.....


#~~~ step 2: write a function to plot the data and save the plot ~~~

saveplot_functionx <- function(i){

    # first we make the plot

     # we take the long format data    
     my_plot <- my_data_long %>%  

      # then we keep only one 'key' (column in the 'wide' data format)
      filter(  
        key == i
      ) %>%

      # and make a plot (you didnt specify the type of plot, but this can be changed as you please)
      ggplot(aes(GW, value))+
      geom_point()+
      ylab(i)     

    # then we save the plot (including variable name in title)
    #***NOTE*** this saves plots into a new folder 'my_folder', which you need to create in your working directory
    ggsave(paste0('my_folder/my_plot_', i, '.pdf'), my_plot)

  }


#~~~ step 3: loop through all the values of 'key' (column names in the wide format data) ~~~

 for(i in unique(my_data_long$key)){
    
    saveplot_function(i)
    
  }
```

Of course you can customise the plots, including labels, titles, colours, sizes, formats etc, but this should give you an idea on how it can be achieved.

I don't fully understand what you are after in terms of normalising the data etc, so I will leave that part up to someone more useful than me.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your help!
By running this code I managed to automatically export one graph for each Pz (which is great!). However, it is not exactly what I needed (I do apologise, I didn't clearly explain what I was after).

So basically both GW and Pz are Y axis to be displayed as `geom_line()`, whilst the X axis can be anything, it doesn't really matter.

Now, running the code you kindly wrote gives one plot for each Pz. Is it possible to obtain multiple plots for each Pz interval? (i.e, Plot#1= GW (fixed), Pz1 (first 14 numbers), Plot#2= GW (fixed), Pz1 (14 numbers shifted by 1 from the previous), Plot#3= GW (fixed), Pz1 (14 numbers shifted by 1 from the previous), Plot#4= GW (fixed), Pz1 (14 numbers shifted by 1 from the previous)... etc... . When the column (or the row in the case the data are transformed in 'long' format) finishes, it starts from the one next to it (i.e., finishes all Pz1, and starts with Pz2).

Please see attached Excel document for clarification!

https://easyupload.io/pvxohj

Thanks a lot for your help, I really appreciate it!